# Change keyboard shorcuts? alsamixer

Tags: sound, alsa, volume-control

I use "master mono" for my audio. I like using the volume up and volume down buttons on my keyboard but they only change "master" not "master mono". Anyway to change this?

Comment: Is "master mono" a channel in the Alsa Mixer? If it is, can you add the output of `amixer scontrols` to the question.

Comment: The volume keys are handled not by alsamixer but by your desktop environment. Which one?

Comment: Please provide the output of 'amixer scontrols' as @mikewhatever requested. To the best of my knowledge (and testing over numerous platforms)  there is no master mono channel in Alsa mixer